# Alguem pode fazer o upload do Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic, apache-cordova, android-sdk

Eu tenho um computador so que a conexão com internet é muito lenta. Gostaria de pedir pra alguém que ja instalou o Android SDK fizesse o upload para o Google drive para eu poder baixar pelo celular e enviar para o computador. Por favor preciso muito, muito, muito mesmo da vossa ajuda

Comment: Quantas serão as variedades de malware que podem ser inoculadas a partir dum Android SDK disponibilizado por um hacker anônimo, desconhecido e leitor dessa página que pode habitar em qualquer canto do mundo vivendo apenas de extrair dados de computadores infectados com executáveis disponibilizados gratuitamente no Google Drive,

Comment: Essa troca de cópias no Google Drive viola os termos da [licença do Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/terms) *3.4 Você não pode usar o SDK para qualquer finalidade não expressamente permitida pelo Contrato de Licença. Exceto na medida exigida pelas licenças de terceiros aplicáveis, você **não pode copiar** (exceto para fins de backup), modificar, adaptar, **redistribuir**, descompilar, fazer engenharia reversa, desmontar ou criar trabalhos derivados do SDK ou de qualquer parte do SDK.*

Comment: Além de que esse site não é fórum ou rede social ou site de troca de aplicativo. O Stack Overflow em Português é um site técnico de perguntas e respostas em língua português cujo o foco é exclusivo em linguagens de programação

Comment: A cópia ou redistribuição do SDK por qualquer meio é vedada salvo em casos de backup, que não é o seu caso.

Comment: Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045).

Comment: Como os comentários se estenderam demais, os que fogem do objetivo do site e escopo foram removidos e deixadas apenas as orientações relevantes (sem necessidade de mover para um chat específico). Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler ao menos [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70). A [help] pode ser útil também.